# Windows not booting off external disc drive

Tags: macos, startup, optical-drive, windows

I'm trying to install windows xp on Lion. This is a little bit complicated, but I was using [this](http://danieltharp.com/weblog/2012/04/how-to-install-windows-xp-sp3-on-mac-osx-lion-and-get-drivers-too/) tutorial. I got to step 6, which is booting from the Windows XP disc. But it says "no bootable medium found -- insert boot disc and press any key." I think the problem is occurring because I am using an external dvd drive, because my internal one is broken. Why is this occurring.

Here is an image of the partitions from within disk utility:
[image: Partitions from within disk utility]

Note: The image says the partition is formatted "Mas OS Extended (Journaled)" but it is actually  "MS - DOS (FAT)" It is like this because I formatted it using the disk utility on the install media for Snow Leopard.

Comment: You are probably right that this is something to do with the external DVD drive. You might be better off creating a bootable USB installer, for example using the instructions [here](http://reboot.pro/topic/17327-tutorial-install-windows-xp-from-usb-in-a-simple-way/).

Comment: @zelanix that's a good idea. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find instructions to do that on a mac. Do you know of anywhere I could find instructions.

Comment: No, good point! Maybe [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69529/64910) can help you. It links to [this](http://evan.borgstrom.ca/post/1314205955/osx-bootable-usb-from-iso) which isn't the most straightforward method but may work for you. Tbh, I have never done this on a mac but I'm sure it's possible. Maybe it's easier to do it on a windows machine (if you have access to one) using [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: @zelanix hmmmm, I've already looked at that. I'm going to use my VM to just do it using rufus.

Comment: Working on it, annoying VM not allowing USB drive through properly.