# Download OS update only once for all home computers

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, data-transfer, folders

I want to upgrade all my home computers (4 macbooks running 10.8) to the new Mavericks OS.

I have a download cap, so i dont want to download it 4 times. How can i download it once and install it on all computers?

Answer (score 2):

To quote Bryan Luby from "[Re-use Mavericks install file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106073/re-use-mavericks-install-file)"

> Download the update from the App Store. Once the file has finished downloading, check your Applications folder for the "Install OS X Mavericks" icon. Copy this installer to your other computers before going through the install process. The installer will delete itself after the install is finished.

I recommend distributing the file between computers via AirDrop (if all your computers support it) or via File Sharing (from the Sharing pane of System Preferences).

***Note:*** Running the update from `/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app` will DELETE the installer upon completion! Be sure to distribute the file to all your machines before installing it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to copying and running the installer from within Mac OS X, you can also [create a bootable USB flash drive](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/10/how-to-make-your-own-bootable-os-x-10-9-mavericks-usb-install-drive/) to install Mavericks on a Mac without any prep.