# How to create a bootable USB for Mac OS X Server 3.0.2?

Tags: macos, usb, server.app, bootable-disk

I have the latest version of OS X Server (Version 3.0.2) downloaded of the App Store and basically I want to create a bootable USB for the installer.

However, looking at it, I'm not able to find the InstallESD.dmg and therefore I'm not sure how I can create a bootable image from this.

Does anyone know how to create a bootable for the latest server version of OS X Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server.app is just a set of scripts and apps that run on top of the base OS X. So just follow the [guides for 10.9 USB media](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110934/os-x-mavericks-installesd-dmg-and-basesystem-dmg).

So, I just carry a second USB drive with server.app and other downloads and use the first drive to install the OS, the second to outfit that image after it it running.

Comment: I tried doing that with by adding this in the terminal:

sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Server.app --nointeraction

But I'm left with the terminal saying command not found

Comment: @user243318 Server app **is not** a bootable image. I'll try to edit my answer to make the second step clear.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! I really appreciate it! :)