# How to create a bootable Mavericks dvd (double layer)?

Tags: macos, startup

my macbook's hard-drive is dead so i bought a new one and i'm looking for a way to install os X on it.

Is it possible to download mavericks on an imac running 10.6.8 and create a bootable dvd ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable USB flash drive for a MacBook Air?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-for-a-macbook-air)

Comment: The link in the comment above shows how to make a bootable USB flash drive. Would this help in your situation as well or must it be a DVD?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Diskmaker X obtainable from http://liondiskmaker.com to make a bootable memory key.