# Install Mavericks via an HD partition

Tags: macos, install

I had a problem trying to clean the data from my Mac and now I can not start it.
It ran Mavericks. I tried to make a swipe date but did not work and lost the system. I have backups of my personal files more unfortunately I do not have the system.
Is there any way to install Mavericks again through a partition of an external HD?
I already have this HD two images of the maverick acquired in apple store. One is the .dmg extension and the other is in .iso extension that I converted in linux.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you please clarify what "I can not start it" means? Where exactly does the startup fail?

Comment: After the start, he will have to OS X utilities and when I click on the Reinstall OS X, I get a message that "this item is unavailable, please try again later."

Comment: Also, what year is your computer from?

Comment: 3 years.  :D   Is there solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is to go to an Apple Store and use an installer CD. Put the CD in your Mac's disk reader and boot from that. To do this, press the power button and hold the `option`, or `alt`, key. Select the CD (it will have an icon) and follow on-screen instructions. If your Mac does not have a disk reader, you will need to use an external one.

---

---

Your second option is to put the Mavericks installer on an external drive.
You will need another Mac for this.
You can find similar instructions on the internet by searching for

```
mac os mavericks installer usb
```

These instructions involve erasing disks. Make sure you are using the correct disk for each step. If you are unsure of what you are doing, ask for help. To avoid erasing the wrong disks, make sure you only have one disk plugged in at a time and never touch "Macintosh HD" on the Mac you are using to format the disk.

*Option 1 to put installer on external drive:*
Taken from [this answer by dewaldcels](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153162/imac-wont-boot-off-of-mavericks-usb-when-downgrading-from-yosemite)
1. Download Mavericks for the App store.
2. Plug in the USB drive you want to boot from (has to be 8GB or more)
3. Then from the Terminal app run this command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app
```

In this command it says `--volume  /Volumes/MyVolume`. You need to replace `MyVolume` with the name of your disk. To get the name, go to Finder and find your disk. The name of the disk is the name you need to put instead of `MyVolume`. If your disk is partitioned, use the name of the partition you want to use.
**I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS. THIS COULD ERASE THE PARTITION, SO USE ONE YOU DON'T NEED.**
This will take a while.

*Option 2 to put installer on external drive:*
1. Borrow another Mac (from friend or Apple Store)
2. Get a copy of Mavericks (either from a backup or App Store or an actual Apple Store) [1]
3. Right click the installer app and click "Show Package Contents"
4. Find InstallESD.dmg inside
5. Open InstallESD.dmg
6. Open Disk Utility [2]
7. Attach a USB/SD card/external hard drive **that you are not using** with at least 8GB of memory
8. Reformat it to use the GUID Partition Scheme and Mac OS Extended (Journaled) format **[3]**
9. Select InstallESD.dmg in the sidebar on the left
10. On the right, click the tab labeled "Restore"
11. In the sidebar on the left you will see the external storage device you attached in Step 7. It will have the name of the type of device you used [4]. Under this you will see the name of the partition (the name you see in Finder). It must be at least 8GB [5]. Drag it into the right side into the box labeled "Destination"
12. Click "Restore". This process will take a while. **The disk must be formatted correctly. See [3]**
13. Eject your drive
14. Plug it into your other Mac (the one you want Mavericks on)
15. Press the power button and hold the `option` key (also known as `alt` key)
16. Select the partition that you just reformatted. It should say "Install Mac OS X 10.9" or something similar.
17. Follow onscreen instructions to install Mavericks on your hard drive (Macintosh HD)

---

Notes
[1] The name of the app is "Install Mac OS X Mavericks.app". You might have backed it up using Time Machine. If not, download it from the App Store. Otherwise, ask a friend or an Apple Store employee.

[2] Ways to open Disk Utility:
1. Open Spotlight (click the magnifying glass in the top right corner or use a keyboard shortcut), type "disk utility" and it should be the first result)
2. Open Launchpad and search "Disk Utility" (OS 10.8+) or open the Utilities folder and click "Disk Utility"
3. Open Finder, click the "Go" menu, and click "Utilities". Then open Disk Utility.app

[3] **Warning:** reformatting a partition erases all its contents.
Select your disk in the sidebar. Click the "Partition" tab. At the bottom, find the text "Partition Map Scheme". If it says "GUID Partition Table" use Method 2 below. Otherwise, use Method 1.
Method 1 **(erases disk)**:
**WARNING** This erases the entire disk.
Select your disk in the sidebar. On the right, under "Partition", click the "Partition Layout" drop-down menu and select "1 partition". To the right, select the "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" format. Click "Apply".
Method 2 **(erases partition)**:
**WARNING** This erases the selected partition.
Select your disk in the sidebar. Under the disk, select the partition (name you see in Finder). Click the "Erase" tab, select the "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" format, and click "Erase...".

[4] If you used an SD card, it will say "SDXC Reader Card Media" or something similar. If you used a hard drive or a USB, it will have its capacity and the manufacturer, or something similar.

[5] To see the size of your partition, select your disk in the sidebar on the left. Under the "Partition" tab, make sure the text box labeled "Size" contains a number greater than 8 and says "GB" to the right of it. If it does not have enough memory, you might have to use a different disk or re-partition and reformat it (see [3] above)

Comment: Ok. But all links in google say: 'get the mavericks on app store'. But, dont exists any more the mavericks in app store. so..??

Comment: I managed to install the version Mac OS X 10.6.8 with a cd. But now, I cant upgrade to yosemite. Any way, I do not want it. Every body says: 'its bad'. And now? Is there solution to install the mavericks considering that I have a mac installation?

Comment: Finally I finish this. Here the link: http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure if Mavericks was still availabile on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error message because OS X Mavericks isn't available for download by the Recovery HD anymore, deleted in favor of Yosemite. Your best bet is to use Internet Recovery. Make sure you're on a decent Internet connection (Ethernet is best, if possible) and follow these instructions:

1. Immediately after hearing the Mac boot chime, hold down Command+Option+R – if you see the Apple logo you waited too long and need to reboot and try again
2. Eventually, you’ll see the familiar “OS X Utilities” screen, choose “Reinstall OS X” to begin the re-installation process of the Mac operating system
3. Select the destination and complete the re-installation (or installation) of OS X as usual

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/14/reinstall-os-x-mac-internet-recovery/)

Comment: In proccess. Thanks for the faster answer buddy. :)

Comment: The same error. :(

Comment: A small detail. He tried to install Mac OS X Lion. : /

Comment: Yeah, the site mentions that it'll try to install the OS version that your computer came with, but it's worked for me. I have another idea, but you'd need to have another Mac and an 8GB flash drive on hand. Do you?

Comment: Nops. I'have a linux debian and a external hd with 1TB. Is there a miracle to do? haha

Comment: Is there some os x with 4GB or less? I can install it and after update to another.

Comment: I don't think there's an OS X version that's less than 4GB and still available for download. Are you willing to make an 8GB partition on your external HD? Alternatively, if you have an 8GB SD card (like in a camera) that you don't need any more, you can donate it to the cause.

Comment: You can use [this link](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293168-guide-how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-109-mavericks-usb-install-drive-on-linux/) to make a bootable OS X drive using your Linux machine and the copy of Mavericks that you have on your external HD.

Comment: I already have a partition with 10 GB free on my hd.

Comment: It's not just about free space. The disk will have to get totally reformatted. Make sure that partition doesn't contain any files that you want to keep, and then it should work!

Comment: Yes. Its was I said. I have a partition with 10GB. I will try with the link above.

Comment: Good luck! Once you've made a bootable drive, you should be able to plug it into your Mac, hold down Option as you boot up, select your bootable drive from a list of startup disks, and enter a version of Recovery HD that comes with Mavericks already completely downloaded and ready for install!

Comment: Did not work with the hd. Th files are in hd but the mac does not recognize it. omg!!

Comment: Okay... new idea. [Make an OS X virtual machine.](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows) (I know it says Windows, but it should work on VirtualBox for Linux too.) Upgrade it to Mavericks using the dmg on your external drive, and then [make a bootable OS X drive the way a bootable OS X drive was meant to be made.](http://www.macworld.com/article/2056561/how-to-make-a-bootable-mavericks-install-drive.html)