# Bootable USB with Ubuntu does not show in boot sequence options

Tags: macos, usb, unix, bootable-disk

I followed [this question (How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB stick Using OS X 10.10.2)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179781/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-stick-using-os-x-10-10-2#) to turn the Ubuntu 14.04 ISO to a bootable USB.

I have a MBP (with touchbar) running 10.12.5.

After rebooting while pressing the <kbd>option</kbd> key, I don't see the USB drive listed. I only see the SSD listed.

What could be wrong?

### Update

The comments suggested my Partition Map was not of the right type. So I erased the USB using Journaled option and select GUID Partition Map. After it's completion (verified with `Diskutil list`) I rebooted to see that the USB is still not listed as a bootable option.

Any other ideas?

Comment: It's important to make sure the USB disk is using a GUID Parition Table (GPT), as this is the format that both macOS and Linux boot disks use. If you formatted it using either Master Boot Record (MBR) or Apple Partition Map (APM) the disk will likely not show up in the list of boot disks. Please check which partition map the USB disk is using (*Disk Utility>USB Disk>Info*). If its using the wrong map, try erasing the disk and setting the map to GPT. If it's already using GPT then additional options might be needed when writing the image to disk.

Comment: Cool will check. This seems like an answer rather than a comment to me :)

Comment: It seems that after I use the `dd` command the partition map changes to `Apple_Partition_scheme` :( - is it wrong usage of the `dd` command?

Comment: Nope, it seems like you're using the command correctly. My guess is that the image you're writing is formatted as Apple Partition Map because it's meant for use with older Power PC Macs. It's also an important point that when writing a Linux image to a USB device on macOS Disk Utility will usually claim the drive isn't readable to the computer if it burned properly. Does the version of Ubuntu have to be 14.04? If not I can look around and find another image.

Comment: Here is a link to the default [Ubuntu 16.04LTS image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.2/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso). Newer Macs generally don't require special versions of Linux installers anymore, so it should work just fine. Same as last time make sure the disk is formatted GPT with HFS+ before writing, and just `dd` or `dcfldd` it to the disk like any other image.

Comment: @AlisonE.E. first of all thanks a lot!
Secondly - please move the info to an answer so I can mark it at the end
Thirdly and unfortunately, it has to be version 14.04 since I want to use it as a dev env for ROS Indigo...
Will search the web for an image that says what MBR it holds