# Why is downloaded online recovery data deleted after reboot?

Tags: macbook-pro, internet-recovery

I recently got a MacBook Pro. Its hard drive is completely empty. So every time I hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> it goes to the internet recovery mode and takes hours to download data recovery. However, when I restart my system, every downloaded data seems to disappear, and it re-downloads recovery mode data. Does anybody know how can I make recovery drive permanent?

Comment: Why do you need to boot recovery every day? Sounds like a bigger issue to me.

Comment: @rob OK. you know I don't have proper internet connection and OSX el capitan is around 6 gigabyte, and I have an image of osx with .app extension. I need to use its terminal to convert .app file to .dmg and make a bootable osx.

Comment: So - is this really about making an offline installer as opposed to caching the recovery (which then kicks off a download?) - if so, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213522/5472

Comment: @bmike can I execute createinstallmedia file within linux command line? I'm about to read the link you sent.

Comment: @ShaD No, you can't use the command `createinstallmedia` in a Linux environment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting to Internet Recovery Mode boots directly to a netboot image provided by Apple/Akamai servers. The netboot image is a stripped down OS X version which only provides some diagnostic tools and a tool to either restore OS X or a Time Machine backup. The downloaded OS is completely loaded to RAM and nothing is written to hard disks.

After shutting down/rebooting the Mac the RAM is wiped and everything has to be downloaded again if you want to start to Recovery Mode a second time.

To create a Recovery HD on your Mac you have to install OS X (Restore OS X). While downloading and installing OS X a recovery partition will be built also.

Another option is to set up a Mac running Server.app and [enable caching services](https://help.apple.com/serverapp/mac/5.1/#/apd74DDE89F-08D2-4E0A-A5CD-155E345EFB83). That will keep a copy of the recovery image locally in cache and speed up the download - perhaps 100x as fast if you have a gigabit speed network locally.

Comment: I didn't know it was stored on my RAM. It is a good news. I thought maybe the HDD act weirdly. thanks god :) . But downloading osx is a pain in the neck respected to my internet connection. I already download a .app extension el capiton and I just need terminal recovery to convert it to DMG and build a bootable image.

Comment: @ShaD Please add a second question how to create a bootable installer from the downloaded OSXInstaller app. You'd have to provide the following information: where is the app stored and do you have a USB thumb drive?

Comment: Hmm good point about another question. I'll try that