# MacBook Pro Hard drive crashed

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro 15". I woke up one day, but my Mac didn't. I was getting nothing but a blank screen so I tried to shut it down a reboot it. Now it won't boot up.. I get the white screen as it tried to boot and th processing bar starts to fill up, but it never finishes. I have been told it's the hard drive.

I am ready to install a new SSD Samsung evo 850 drive, but how am I supposed to install the OS? Design is no longer my main career and I don't need a lot of the programs and extra stuff I once had. I also have most everything saved in the cloud so I would rather start fresh and not transfer the old OS over.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201257) to confirm first.  Basically boot your Mac up and hold the `D` key and you will be prompted for some instructions.

To reinstall your Mac with new SSD you can try the [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201314). For this one you boot up your Mac holding down the `Command + R` keys.  It will take a very long time to complete depending on the speed of your Internet connection.  According to Apple this only works if you had OS X Lion or later.  I have also had mixed success with the Internet Recovery.

Second option to reinstall your Mac is to get a friend with a Mac to create a bootable USB for you.  I won't go into the details on how to create a bootable Mac USB because there is tons of questions like this on Stack Exchange already.  This would be my preferred way of reinstalling.

Creating bootable USB Links

[How do I make a bootable USB flash drive a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-a-mac)

Comment: Thank you.  I do have an old G3 tower. I'll  have to check on which OS is installed. I think it's Lion. I'll read up on the bootable USB drive methods.

Comment: I would put the new SSD in the Mac Book Pro and give the Internet Recovery a try.  Worst thing that can happen is it won't work.  Bootable USB is not very difficult either if you have a friend with Yosemite or El Capitan; with Mavericks or below, its a bit more effort.