# iMac mid 2011 doesn't boot

Tags: hard-drive, imac, startup

I have a problem with a iMac mid 2011. It doesn't boot anymore.
When booting, you only see a folder with a question mark, that's it.

Troubleshooting done:

- boot from the same HDD on another iMac mid 2011: OK
- boot the defect iMac with the HDD from the working iMac: Not OK
- added an extra sata-cable and connected the HDD to that cable: Not OK
- tried to boot to diagnostics and safe mode: Not OK
- reset NVRAM and PRAM: Not OK

What can I try more to get this iMac working again?

Comment: What’s “NOK”. For example... “reset NVRAM and PRAM: NOK”. What does that mean? Resetting was NOT OK?  How so?  Did the reset fail somehow?

Comment: Hi @Allan,the resets where done, but it didn't helped to start the iMac.

Comment: Also, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236749/119271

Comment: If you HDD works in a different machine, its’s obviously not the drive.  It’s likely the SATA controller or related subsystems. See the suggested duped.

Comment: I found the solution, the sata controller was broken. I replaced the logic board, and the iMac starts again :)