# How to Install OSX back in Macbook Air?

Tags: macos, install

I have Macbook Air 2013-mid which has only Ubuntu 16.04 and reFind bootloader. Now, however, I Would like get OSX back to the whole disk. I find only updates of specific OS Xs [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos) but not whole ISO file, which you can boot for the install. I have had licences of El Capitan on my Apple store but cannot login now to any Apple store.

I started the Internet recovery mode. It asks me wifi password. I gave it but it stays now in the mode where the Earth and you can still change the network settings. I have also Ethernet connection with USB connector to the device but it does not want to use it. 
Eventually, it gives the warning sign and the text

```
apple.com/support
-2002F
```

Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit only at the moment

Comment: I think Internet Recovery is the way to go; Cmd/opt/R at boot. That will install the OS that the machine was shipped with, then you can update.

Comment: @Tetsujin I started the recovery mode. It asks me wifi password. I gave it but it stays now in the mode where the Earth and you can still change the network settings. I have also Ethernet connection with USB connector to the device but it does not want to use it.

Comment: wifi needs to be WPA/WPA2, not WEP & no captive portals. If you still can't connect, then you need a friend with a Mac who can get the El Cap installer & make a USB boot, or take it to your nearest Apple Store; they'll set it up for you.

Comment: @Tetsujin Please, see the body. I will next make El Cap installation with USB boot with another mac. Is there any specific which I need to consider?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-a-mac