# How can I fix or restore my 3TB Fusion Drive macOS install after Boot Camp partitioning error?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, recovery, fusion-drive

What I have:
 - 27" 2012 Mac with 3TB Fusion Drive
 - 3.4 GHz Core i7 (3770) ("Ivy Bridge") processor
 - 24 GB RAM

I was trying to set it up with a Boot Camp partition for Windows 10. The story so far:

- Machine came with virgin install of Sierra. I restored from my Time Machine backup of my iMac 9,1 (also with Sierra installed), and everything worked normally.
- The new machine inherited the Time Machine backup from the old one and was fully backed up.
- I ran Boot Camp Assistant to download the Boot Camp files, put the Windows 10 iso on a flash drive, and partition the disk.
- During this process, I was only able to choose a maximum partition size for Windows of 640 GB, with the Mac partition being about 2454 GB if I recall correctly.
- The partitioning failed with an error message, and it told me to repair the disk in Disk Utility
- I went to Disk Utility and performed repair (on the 'whole disk' and the disk volume named Macintosh HD). No problems were found and the repair exited normally.
- I continued with Boot Camp Assistant, which had stayed open, and tried to partition the disk again. As before, 640 GB was the maximum allowable for Windows.
- The process appeared to hang, I left it for over half an hour before force quitting. I guess this was a bad mistake, perhaps it just takes a long time anyway.
- After force quitting, the Mac slowed to a crawl. I entered Disk Utility which showed the capacity as about 3 TB and the used space about 0.04 TB less than that. Before this, the used space was about 1.6 TB.
- I ran First Aid in Disk Utility and after this process the Disk Capacity was reduced to 1.67 TB with 0.04 TB free. The computer continued to run at a crawl, presumably because of the lack of free space on the disk.
- I booted off my Time Machine backup, which booted into the recovery environment.
- I erased the Fusion Drive, which restored the capacity to 3TB.
- Next, possibly another big mistake, I chose Restore and then chose my Time Machine disk. But I did this from inside Disk Utility rather than from the main menu of the recovery environment.
- The restore completed and verified. The Fusion Drive was now named 2TBTimeMachine instead of Macintosh HD.
- When I tried to reboot, the Apple logo appeared with a progress bar, and then a grey screen with a circle with a diagonal line through it.
- I booted from the Time Machine disk again (to the recovery environment). I ran First Aid, first on the whole disk, which appeared to fix one thing. I can't remember what this was but I remember it said '1 newer' of whatever it changed.
- I then ran First Aid on the disk named 2TBTimeMachine (i.e. the Fusion Drive), which found several problems and reported that it successfully fixed them. I'm sorry, I don't remember what issues it found and fixed.
- I tried rebooting again, which led to the same circle with diagonal line. Before that, I tried to select the startup disk from the recovery environment, which showed no startup disks available at all.
- Currently I am redoing the Time Machine backup from my old Mac and intend to try and restore that to the new Mac. I am writing this from the Internet Recovery Environment on my new Mac.

I have a few questions:

- What mistakes did I make in the process above?
- Will I be able to restore to the new disk without erasing it first (i.e. will it replace all content on the disk)? The reason I ask is because the Internet Recovery Environment seems to have an older version of Disk Utility, and I don't want to risk erasing the disk from this version of Disk Utility in case it doesn't know about Fusion Drives.
- Is there any benefit to installing Mac OS X Mountain Lion from the Internet Recovery Environment? I don't know why Mountain Lion is the only option here. Is it likely to cause further problems if I install Mountain Lion and from that install upgrade to Sierra?
- Do I need to 'rebuild' the Fusion Drive and can you provide or direct me to a clear set of instructions for doing this?

Comment: Your main mistake was:  "I chose Restore and then chose my Time Machine disk. But I did this from inside Disk Utility rather than from the main menu of the recovery environment.AFAIR this simply makes a copy of your Backup volume but doesn't restore the boot volume.

Comment: Thanks klanomath, I suspected as much but it's helpful to have it confirmed.

Comment: If your original TM backup drive still exists, I would boot to Internet Recovery Mode, delete & recreate the Fusion Drive and restore your original Sierra boot volume from the Utilities windows > Restore from Time Machine Backup > Select backup source >....

Comment: I shall do exactly that. My original TM backup doesn't exist but I'm recreating it from scratch with the old Mac. Fortunately I use OneDrive to store almost all of my files and I haven't lost anything I can't easily replace. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm you deleted the already "inherited" content of 2TBTimeMachine and redoing a backup of the iMac9,1 now? - It's a pity that the iMac9,1 doesn't provide a Thunderbolt interface: you would be able to just clone iMac9,1 to the iMac13,2, which is much faster...

Comment: Yes, I omitted to mention that after the Fusion Drive lost 1.4 TB and 'filled up', TM backups continued. Then, since what I thought at the time was a restore from TM using Disk Utility failed to produce a bootable drive, I decided to create the backup anew. I guess it's quite possible, even likely, that had I kept this TM backup I could have used it to restore in the proper manner.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't really necessary to kill the TM backup drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to do the following:

1. Create a [bootable macOS Sierra installer thumb drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/200476/93229) or if you are restricted to your iMac9,1 a bootable El Capitan installer thumb drive (same link).
2. Boot the iMac13,2 with the thumb drive
3. Open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities > Terminal
4. Enter `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` to get an overview
5. Destroy the LVG:

   ```
   diskutil cs delete lvgUUID #lvgUUID: UUID of the Logical Volume Group
   ```
6. Enter `exit` to quit Terminal.app and open Disk Utility
7. Completely erase both disks (each to one volume with the names e.g. "fusion1" and "fusion2" **but not** "Macintosh HD").
8. Open Terminal again and get the device identifiers again: `diskutil list`
9. Create a new LVG and LV (here I assume the 120 GB SSD has the disk identifier disk0 and the 3 TB HDD disk1 - they might be different though!):

   ```
   diskutil cs create Fusion disk0 disk1
   diskutil cs createVolume lvgUUID jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100% #replace lvgUUID with the UUID shown in the output of the previous command
   ```
10. Enter `exit` to quit Terminal.app
11. After finishing the iMac9,1 backup to your TM backup drive, attach the drive to your iMac13,2 and in the Utilities windows choose Restore from Time Machine Backup > Select backup source > ...choose the drive and restore it to your Macintosh HD volume.
12. After the restore task has finished successfully, boot your iMac13,2 normally. Check if a RecoveryHD is present by opening Terminal and entering `diskutil list`.
13. If the RecoveryHD is missing, simply reinstall Sierra with the latest Sierra installer downloaded from the App Store  - which shouldn't affect your data but creates an additional RecoveryHD - or use the [Recovery Partition Creator 4](http://musings.silvertooth.us/downloads-2/).

Comment: Step 1: The iMac 9,1 doesn't officially support Sierra hence the MAS won't allow me to download it, I am running it using the Sierra Patcher for the installer at [link](http://dosdude1.com/sierrapatch.html) and the AUSEnabler tool for updates at [link](http://swdist.furcode.co). I have access to the latest Sierra raw package from the latest comment at [link](https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/macos-sierra-direct-download.html) but I don't know how to convert this into an .app file. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @RichardBrockbank An El Capitan installer is also working.. ElCap is preferred if your are using your iMac9,1 - no hacks!

Comment: Apologies for the unnecessary extra comments (now deleted) if you read them. Your instructions were perfectly clear, I just didn't read and apply them properly. I'm now at Step 11 waiting for the iMac 9,1 backup to complete and the previous steps have all worked exactly as described. I think you've saved me from a lot of stress and possibly saved me money, so -- thank you!

Comment: About ElCap, I found that several persistent and annoying bugs – System Preferences not loading, iCloud error on login, Safari sometimes restarting itself after being quit – cleared up when I upgraded to the patched Sierra and I had no issues at all running the Mac with Sierra. I was a little concerned about leaving SIP disabled of course but I felt it was worth the risk.

Comment: I've completed the steps above. Although the RecoveryHD _is_ present, I'm going to reinstall Sierra anyway and then turn on SIP, because the TM backup was of the patched version of Sierra.