# MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) Does not Enter Recovery Mode

Tags: ssd

I am booting up by CMD + R.

Internet recovery globe icon appears. It downloads something for 2 minutes and then restart the macbook pro.

After restart nothing happens. It tries to boot up normally. But because I am trying to install onto an empty formatted Sandisk SSD drive, obviously no help.

After another CMD + R attempt, the internet recovery globe downloads for 2 minutes and then internet recovery globe dismiss. After that without restart, gray Apple icon appears with a loading bar under it. Tries to progress but halts at 70 percent and progress freezes. Waited 15 minutes without any progress change and hard quitted. Not sure if it is downloading a big OS ISO image or something.

Also I am trying to boot up by C key with a Snow Leopard DVD that comes with the Macbok Pro. After 5 minutes, the throbber under Apple icon just halts and screen freezes.

May it be because the SSD drive is not recognized?

How can I fix this issue?

Is it possible to see the verbose output of CMD + R recovery attempt?

Comment: You certain it's an 08? Internet recovery was not an option back then. See https://support.apple.com/HT202313

Comment: I've used a Sandisk SSD with a late-2007 MBP, so that probably isn't the problem.  Though I don't think I fresh-installed to it, just moved an existing OSX install from a SSHD.  I wonder if there's a diagnostics CD you can use?

Comment: @Tetsujin I might be wrong about the year but I remember it is 2008. Maybe 2010 but not earlier. Rotating globe has under saying "starting internet recovery. this may take a while"

Comment: Then it's not an 08... without knowing exactly what it is, help is limited. Try https://everymac.com/mac-identification/index-how-to-identify-my-mac.html

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right, I checked serial number from Apple site. It is MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)

Comment: @Chromatix when I boot up with D key, it does not enter into Apple Hardware Test either. Is it possible to get verbose mode of CMD + R? Also is it possible to get the image of the diagnostics CD? I googled but could not find.

Comment: The 2010 can't use the internet AHT, even if upgraded - my first link. Best shot might be a USB installer - ref: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-a-mac/200476

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks. I found the Applications Install DVD that came with the MBP. Run the Hardware test. There was an error with the fan but nothing more. Fan is noisy but working. I think the problem is not about the fan. But not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try [bootable disk drive utility](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/306999/Doesn%27t+install+OS+X%2C+can%27t+boot+into+recovery+mode) method;
Here is how this process works. First, it's necessary for you to prepare a USB flash drive. With that you can create and install a bootable OS X installer drive and then to fix Mac not working in recovery mode issue.
For that;
1.Reboot Mac and keep taping “Option” until you hear the sound.
2.Attach your bootable installer drive to Mac and choose it from the pop up list.
3.Then your Mac will restart and you are able to fix Mac.

Comment: Thanks. I created a bootable usb. After Option boot up, I plug it, select it. Grey apple logo appears with a circling throbber. After 1 minute, throbber freezes and screen stalls. Have to hard quit.