# Restoring a white Macbook with OSX Lion

Tags: macos, recovery

I'm trying to restore an old Macbook for my kid. I've erased the hard drive and want to reinstall the OS, which is Lion. However, I have a problem - I have no idea what Apple ID I used originally (nearly 13 years ago) on this machine, so I can't do the usual 'Reinstall Mac OS X' option. If I try and log in with another Apple ID, it just says it's temporarily unavailable.

I have also tried to reboot into Internet Recovery Mode using Option + Cmd + R, but it just reboots to normal recovery mode.

It also appears to be impossible to safely and legally download a copy of an old OSX version to create a separate recovery disk.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have another Mac see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Comment: @Tetsujin ok... the special version of El Capitan seems to be the thing... how do I actually install it though?

Comment: You will possibly have to go through https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-on-a-mac/200476#200476 - but I'm afraid it's not something I can test here, sorry.