# Creating bootable USB from "Install OS X El Capitan.iso"

Tags: macos, usb, bootable-disk, iso

I have "Install OS X El Capitan.iso" file. I have burned the image to a DVD and successfully installed El Capitan in the past. Now that my DVD drive is broken, I would like to create a bootable USB Drive out of it. Can this be achieved? If yes, I'd like to know how.

Comment: Answer to your questions: **Yes**. I assume you would like to know how this works? Then check https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 or just google *create bootable usb drive from .iso mac*. You will find many examples since there are multiple ways to achieve it, for basically all OS versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a bootable USB flash drive on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7152/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-on-a-mac)

Comment: Where did this 'iso' come from? That's not a format that Apple distributes OS installers in, as far as I know. MacOS installers usually come as .app, .pkg, or .dmg.

Comment: Yes I am wondering the same thing. Sounds like he downloaded a torrent file or something. Pretty dangerous if you ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I did was wrote the image to USB Drive with dd command from the terminal and it booted like a charm. The command I used was:

```
$ diskutil list
$ cd /path/to/Install_OS_X_10.11_El_Capitan.iso
$ sudo dd if=Install_OS_X_10.11_El_Capitan.iso of=/dev/disk2 bs=1m
```

Replace `disk2` with the appropriate drive listed in the output of the first command. For example, disk3 or disk4.

Comment: Please at least modify your question. You are asking **if** it is possible, not **how**. Also, this may be a duplicate question/answer and the answer is not very precise: Explain the steps you did and make them as clear as possible. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please share the complete dd command line.