# OSstatus -22 Error, Disk Utility in Catalina

Tags: macos, disk-utility, catalina

I have an OSstatus -22 error with Catalina while trying to restore any ISO/DMG to a USB flash drive using Disk Utility. I can use the terminal option just fine, but does anyone know of a reason why this error appears? I never had it under Mojave. Been looking for a solution to flash old PowerPC images in Apple Partition Format; used to work fine without any 3rd party tools. This is the closest solution I came to: [Disk Utility fails with OSStatus error 22 during cloning/recovery operation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384573/disk-utility-fails-with-osstatus-error-22-during-cloning-recovery-operation)

Thanks!